# How I can justify the first choice $T$ to garantee that all the elements are not zeros?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let  $A$ be a finite set, then it is possible to find a bijection $$θ:A→T={1,2,...,n}$$ where $T$ is a finite part of natural numbers ℕ. Also, it is possible to find a bijection $$ψ:A→D={0,1,2,...,n-1}$$ where $D$ is a finite part of natural numbers ℕ, and so on... where the second set is finite and contain any kind of real numbers. I am interested on the first case where all the numbers are not zeros. But the existence of other possibilities create some doubts for me.

So my **question** is: How I can justify the first choice $T$ to garantee that all the elements are not zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\psi\colon A\to D$ then $\theta(a)=\psi(a)+1$ is the bijection you want. All you have to prove is that $n\mapsto n+1$ is an injective function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$ and that every non-zero number is in its range.